# Merging accounts -- one account has a StackExchange OpenID attached to it

Tags: support, login, merge-accounts, stack-exchange, openid

I have two accounts on SO (this one, and an old one that's more or less abandoned on SO itself) due to what basically amounts to a historical accident.  HOWEVER: I have logins on 4 SE member sites that are all based on a SE OpenID that is tied to the same email/login as the *OLD* SO account!  What will happen to the OpenID if I have the old SO account merged to the new SO account?

## More gory details from the comments

So, I created a SO account a few years ago to ask a real nasty bugger of a question -- this account was based on a personal email address as that was the only one I had at the time.  Fast-forward a few years, and I ran into another real bugger of a question, but didn't recall I had an SO account already at that point in time, so I created another SO account -- but during the process of asking the question, I found an answer on SO that answered it.

Later on, I got involved on a few SE sites -- but wound up basing my SE logins on the old SO login (SE OpenID) due to my new SO login being based on my work email.   I now want to have the 125-odd rep and one, solitary question on my old SO account merged into my new SO account, to avoid confusion, potential sockpuppetry accusations, or a forced merge.

HOWEVER: I want the SE OpenID to be unlinked from the old SO account, so that it will not be migrated to the new SO account -- that way, if I ever want to turn email notifications etal on, I won't get a bunch of not-work email in my work email inbox. Is there some sort of switch I can flip on the OpenID that'd allow me to choose a different SE family account as the 'master' or 'owner' for that OpenID token?

Comment: What do you mean "What will happen to the OpenId"?  Are you concerned it will get deleted or removed?  Or something else?

Comment: @psubsee2003: I'm concerned it'll get either a) removed or b) linked to the SO account being merged into, neither of which I want.

Comment: @LThode I doubt it will do anything. I started this account with my email address, then made an SE OpenID with the same email address to tie to this account, and nothing bad's happened. It's just another ID, and therefor another account entirely. It shouldn't wipe out either of your logins.

Comment: I'm confused by what you are actually asking.  Do you want to merge the accounts, or are you trying to figure out what will happen if the accounts accidentally got merged?

Comment: I want to merge the accounts on SO, yes.

Comment: @LThode but you don't want it linked to the old account? (referencing (b) from your initial comment).

Comment: @psubsee2003: I don't want the SE OpenID linked to the *new* account -- that's what I meant by the 'account being merged into'.

Comment: @LThode then I have no clue what you are asking because you are talking about merging accounts but not merging logins?  You might not understand what exactly a merge is in this sense.  Maybe try explaining in more detail what you want to see as an end result?

Comment: So, I created a SO account a few years ago to ask a real nasty bugger of a question.  Fast-forward a few years, and I ran into another real bugger of a question, but didn't recall I had an SO account already at that point in time, so I created *another* SO account -- but during the process of asking the question, I found an answer on SO that answered it.  Later on, I got involved on a few SE sites -- but wound up basing my SE logins on the old SO login (SE OpenID) due to my new SO login being based on my work email.  (continues below...)

Comment: (continued from above) I now want to have the 125-odd rep and one, solitary question on my old SO account merged into my new SO account, to avoid confusion, potential sockpuppetry accusations, or a forced merge.  HOWEVER: I want the SE OpenID to be *unlinked* from the old SO account, so that it will not be migrated to the new SO account -- that way, if I ever want to turn email notifications etal on, I won't get a bunch of not-work email in my work email inbox.  Is there some sort of switch I can flip on the OpenID that'd allow me to choose a different SE family account...(continued again)

Comment: (continued from above, again) ... as the 'master' or 'owner' for that OpenID token?

Comment: @Kendra: what I want is one SO account -- but *disassociated* from the SE network profile that has the 4 SE accounts on it!.

Comment: Yuck!  That seems like a serious infelicity in the way SO/SE accounts are managed -- is there no way for SO staff to do this manually?!

Comment: @LThode: please to [edit] your question to include your clarification.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer here: No.

The longer answer:

If you don't want your new SE OpenID on your old one question account, **do not merge**. If you don't want to be accused of sockpuppetry, the easiest way is to leave that account abandoned. It really won't hurt anything. Trust me, as I've been trying to figure this one out myself, [there is no way to disassociate an account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/how-can-i-disassociate-an-account), which is what you'd be wanting to do. You're already where you'd want to end up.

If you merge, you will have one single, solitary account under your current SE Network Profile.. You will receive the rep and questions/answers of both accounts on one SO account. There will no longer be the "Old account" and the "New account", there will only be one overall "Merged account" that would have the activity from both the original accounts. *They will still both be under your SE Network Profile.*

If you visit the link I include, account disassociation does seem to have been possible at one point, but they appear to have removed that functionality a few years back.

[I don't know if the SE Team will do this upon request. I never received a response to that clarification request.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/how-can-i-disassociate-an-account#comment780032_109054) I assume the answer is "No" but until an SE Team member responds to that issue, there is no official word on that that I have found.